# Using FileSystemWatcher with specified file names

Tags: vb.net, file, filesystemwatcher

Is there a way to do action if file with specified name is created in for example, "C:\" using FileSystemWatcher?

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    If 
         'really don't know what to put here
    End If
End Sub
```

I will explain if you did not understand.

Comment: If you want to do something when a particular file has been created then you need to use a different event handler (created)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have prepared your `FileSystemWatcher1` with these properties

```
Dim FileSystemWatcher1 = New FileSystemWatcher()
FileSystemWatcher1.Path = "C:\"
FileSystemWatcher1.Filter = "*.*"
AddHandler FileSystemWatcher1.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
FileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
.....
```

Then you could write your event handler as you have already done above and look at the property of the `FileSystemEventArgs` argument passed to the event handler to know the exact name of the file created.

```
Private Shared Sub OnCreated(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    If e.Name.ToUpper() == "MYTEXTFILE.TXT" then
        ' do you code here '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tim How about if i read name(s) from textbox?I have list full of file names and I thought this will work,but no luck :  `if e.name.toupper.contains(textbox1.text) then  `